# Difference between an API and API server?

Tags: javascript, api, server

How I understood APIs is that it basically allows communication between 2 applications.

So the client asks for a resource, the request reaches the API, if the asked resource (or end point) exists, the request is delegated to the server, the information is fetched from the database and a response it sent to the user.

So the API is between the client and the server.

If the above is true, what is an API server?

Maybe its a stupid question, but I am just confused.

Comment: API is more like the protocol itself

Answer (score 1):

Well, in short, API stands for Application Programming Interface, it is where you communicate with a "service provider", it can be a server, an application that's locally saved in your system, even a physical device.

API server in the broad web context generally means a server that performs certain actions on request, and those requests are received by API.

Answer (score 0):

An API is hosted on an API server. The server itself is generally a computer on the cloud that runs the code that powers the API. So when you say "the request reaches the API" you are also implicitly saying "the client contacts the API server"

Comment: Okay,so lets say I am creating a server using 'express' and I've created a few GET and POST methods.   Now when my client makes a request, it goes to the server and it sees that a route exists for it and i get response back. And this is where i am confused cause doesn't the API come in between the client and the server? Like Client -> API -> Server.

Comment: You can think of it like an API is basically some code (for example using express) that runs on a server. When you have a server that runs an API, it's called an API server